# Is there a way to run multiple tabs at the same time? Like, all their ```initState``` together

Tags: dart, flutter

I have an app with multiple tabs that contains a ListView, but everytime I swap to the next tab it takes a little time to show the content. What I want is to avoid that little time, running all tabs together, so when the first is done, all of them will be done too.

Comment: Why do they take a little time to show the content? Are they fetching any data?

Comment: Yes, each og them are doing a get to a url and putting the content on a List

Comment: Then you should do all the fetching in the parent widget and pass the data for each child.

Comment: Try to add some parts of your code, it's a good way to let people help you